# Position:fixed on menu bar - hopefully simple

Tags: css, html, menubar, css-position

I am trying to make the top menu bar float at the top of the page here:

http://www.landedhouses.co.uk/

So that when a user scrolls down the menu is still displayed.

Unfortunately adding position:fixed to the CSS doesn't seem to do the trick, various elements still float around. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add on style.css

```
.strip{

position: fixed;
z-index:1;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that seemed to work, although I think the background logo needs to be moved down.

Comment: my pleasure ,try firebug and mozilla web devloper tools these are great tool for web designer and developer